# evaluating trig without a calculator

Tags: trigonometry

Evaluate $\csc^{-1} (\sec 5)$ without using a calculator.

I have no idea where to begin on this problem, I've looked over trig identities, and cannot find one that I think applies. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Lets not forget what cosecant (csc) means. cosecant($\theta$) is the secant of the compliment of $\theta$, where two complimentary angles add up to one quarter rotation ($90^\circ$ or $\pi/2$ rad.).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Let $\alpha=\csc^{-1}\left(\sec 5\right).$ In other words, $\alpha$ is an angle in the first or fourth quadrant, and $\csc\alpha=\sec 5.$ Put another way, $\sin\alpha=\cos 5.$ Do you see why this is the same thing? Can you take it from here, perhaps by drawing a right triangle?

**Note**: You will be able to find an exact value this way. It will ***not*** be a *numerical* answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\csc^{-1}\sec5 = \theta
$$
$$
\sec 5 = \csc\theta
$$
$$
\frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{side adjacent to 5}} = \sec 5 = \csc\theta = \frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{side opposite }\theta}
$$
$$
\text{Hence: }~~~~~\text{side adjacent to 5} = \text{side opposite }\theta
$$
So $5$ and $\theta$ are the two non-right angles in a right triangle.  They add up to a right angle:
$$
\theta+5=\text{right angle}
$$
(If this is supposed to be in degrees, then $\theta=85$.  If it's in radians, we would need the angle between $-\pi/2$ and $+\pi/2$ that has the right cosecant.)